# Change scope value of parent controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a navbar on my index.html and I have a title in this navbar.

I want to change that title based on business logic on each controller of views... each view that I access the title in the navbar from index will change.

The code is something like that:

index.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
...
<div class="navbar" ng-controller="NavbarController">
  {{ navbar.title }}
</div>

<div ngview></div>
...
</html>
```

NavbarController.js

```
...
$scope.navbar.title = "First Value for navbar title";
...
```

SomeController.js

```
...
$scope.navbar.title = "Change navbar title for this";
...
```

I think this is pretty basic but I research a lot about it and i did'nt found a good way to do it.

Comment: try in someController:

require: 'NavbarController',
link: function(scope, element, navbarCtrl){
navbarCtrl.$scope.navbar.title = 'blablabla';
}

Comment: but if someController is really child, it's $scope.$parent.navbar.title = 'blablabla';

Comment: can add additional parameters to route configuration if that helps, then use routing event like `$routeChangeSuccess` to listen for route changes and update your title using a directive on your navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these scenarios, services always come to the rescue:

```
enter code here
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VEdT7/

Watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXpHV5gWgyk&list=TL7hy8sqt0JXtPJ3VGup2lz4TPXYsrSrn3